# Logistic regression vs. negative binomial regression for the same type of data?

Tags: logistic, negative-binomial-distribution

I'm asking this mainly out of curiosity, but few times I've come across data that could be modeled with either logistic or negative binomial regression. For example, there may be an experiment with a binary outcome with some probability of success, and each subjects in the experiment is tested multiple sessions, with multiple trials per session. One option is to treat treat every single trial as an observational unit, and model the data with logistic regression. Another option is to sum the number of successes across session, and then fit a negative binomial regression.

Are there any advantages/disadvantages/outright problems with modeling the data one or the other way?

Comment: If each participant is tested multiple times then you might need random intercepts and/or effects to factor out the correlations of the observations within each participant.

Comment: True! I'm just wondering that after you take care of the nestedness in the data, is there a difference in choosing to model every single response vs the sum of positive responses across some discrete timepoint.